# how do I use microsoft rewards points?

Tags: xbox-network

So every month I get my rewards statement from MS about my XBL rewards...but I have no idea how to use them. I have 24,000 lifetime rewards points. How do I/can I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your current total reaches 5000 it will convert to your local currency and then automatically get added to your microsoft funds at the end of the month (usually). for example, 5000pts converts to $5. You can request and early deposit at anytime as well once you have at least 1000 points. You can see more info about rewards [here](http://rewards.xbox.com/) and more statistics(and manually cash out) on your own rewards [here](http://rewards.xbox.com/myrewards/)

Comment: Thanks! Are lifetime points any different than the credits?

Comment: The lifetime is the total number of credits you've earned since signing up for rewards